# UPDATE before INSERT (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two schemas S1 and S2 with identical table structure. I`ll start with example:

on S1.table1 I have:

```
    ID   DATA1       DATA2
   ---- ---------- ---------- 
    01   data1       test1
    02   data1       test1
```

on S2.table1 I have:

```
     ID   DATA1       DATA2
   ---- ---------- ---------- 
    01   data2       test2
    02   data2       test2
```

**Is it possible to select one row  (from S1.table1) update it (change value of ID column) and insert it into S2.table1?** I want to write single SQL query which will be used as prepared statement (Java).

Final result on S2 should be:

```
     ID   DATA1       DATA2
   ---- ---------- ---------- 
    01   data2       test2
    02   data2       test2
    03   data1       test1
```

so i inserted first row from S1.table1, and changed only ID.

Thanks,
Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
INSERT INTO S2
SELECT 03, DATA1, DATA2 FROM S1 WHERE ID=01
```

That is, you just select the data you want, but explicitly indicate any replacement data.

Comment: Thanks, great idea.

But, what if i do NOT want to list all other columns? 

it`s like:

INSERT INTO S2.table1 (SELECT * FROM S1 Where ID = 01)

but i want to modify the ID column (it is not autogenerated)

Comment: Yeah, that's a tough one.  I've also had occasions where I've wanted a SELECT EVERYTHING EXCEPT command, but there isn't one.  I guess you could simply copy the entire row, and then immediately do an update.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO S2 (Data1, Data2) SELECT Data1, Data2 FROM S1 WHERE ID=xxx
```

Assuming the ID in S2 is autoincremented (via sequence and trigger for instance).

Comment: Use [sequence name].NEXTVAL - there usually isn't a need to do this within a trigger.

Comment: True, but the trigger has the advantage of not requiring you to use the correct sequence. I guess it's a matter of taste.

Comment: The ID column is not autoincremented, I used very simplified example, the table actually contains about 50 columns, and the key column (constraint unique) is not auto generated value.

Comment: @Lucero: "not requiring use of the correct sequence"?  Native tools & isolation levels don't really validate it being a matter of taste...

Answer (score 1):

You must use a sequence:

```
insert into s2.table1
select seq.next_val, data1, data2
from s1.table1
```

The sequence will always count up. So when you run this again, the new rows will be "appended" to the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into s2.table1 (
  select id+1, data1, data2 
  from s1.table1 
  where id=(select max(id) from s1.table1)
);
```